# What are the properties of an 'ideal' pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286261/two-pendulums-same-effective-length-same-bob-mass-but-one-bobs-full-of-water/286265?noredirect=1#comment642788_286265) mentions a phrase *ideal pendulum*.

**What are the properties of an ideal pendulum(if there is any such term)?**

Internet search tells me that there are two types of pendulum:Simple and compound.

Comment: what does internet tell you about those types?

Comment: Whenever in physics the word ideal is used it just means that very special, often unrealistic conditions are assumed. As for an ideal pendulum, physicists usually refer to a pendulum with no attrition - at the pivot(s) - and that air resistance on the pendulum  is zero.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNpuTx7UQbw&index=11&list=PLyQSN7X0ro203puVhQsmCj9qhlFQ-As8e go to 27:45, here he explains an ideal pedulum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal pendulum, as in the question you refer to, is one without friction, air resistance, a point-mass bob - i.e. the bob is not a real massive object but just a point, etc. It's defined that way to make the maths simpler. Real, actual pendulums only behave in approximately the same way.

The ideal pendulum can, however, have any length or bob-weight, so it does not have any special proportions.

Comment: do not forget to mention that for the ideal pendulum the rope has to be massless and fixed length. There is also a small angle limit that I do not remember exactly.

Comment: @linuxick, actually the small angle limit is not necessary for the pendulum to be called ideal, but instead for the approximation by the harmonic oscillator to hold.